# package org.apache.poi.hwpf does not exsist

Tags: java

i am trying to compile some code to test out, and i am recieving some errors

package :

```
org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel
org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor
org.apache.poi.hwpf
```

does not exsist

does anyone know where i can find these packages ?
its to complie a simple piece of code that should just allow the conversion of a docx file to a pdf file

Comment: Edited, anyone can help me find these packages ?

Comment: Have you tried typing "org.apache.poi.hwpf" into Google?

Comment: Yes, i have downloaded the poi-2.0.2-FINIAL jar, but this is not the correct one

Comment: EDIT found it - poi-scratchpad-3.0.1 if anyone needs it

Answer (score 2):

The Word 2007 XML formats are in xwpf as hwpf is for the older versions of Word, for example usermodel is org.apache.poi.**xwpf**.usermodel

The jar for this is under poi-ooxml and currently there is a copy on the maven repo1 at: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.9/

I'm using SBT with these dependancies:

```
// Add multiple dependencies
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.9" % "compile->default",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9" % "compile->default",
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml-schemas" % "3.9" % "compile->default",
  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" % "test->default",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.5" % "test->default",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.6.1" % "test->default"
)
```